# NPM Dependencies Error on CentOS Yum

Tags: node.js, dependencies, centos, npm, yum

My build script installs NPM on CentOS in the following way:

```
yum -y update
yum install -y wget
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
rpm -Uvh remi-release-6*.rpm epel-release-6*.rpm
yum --enablerepo=epel -y groupinstall "Development Tools"
yum --enablerepo=epel -y install npm
```

At some point in the last week, I have been getting the following dependency issue:

```
Error: Package: nodejs-npm-registry-client-0.2.28-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: npm(semver) >= 2.1.0
           Installing: nodejs-semver-2.0.10-1.el6.noarch (epel)
               npm(semver) = 2.0.10
Error: Package: nodejs-request-2.21.0-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: npm(form-data) < 0.1
           Available: nodejs-form-data-0.1.1-1.el6.noarch (epel)
               npm(form-data) = 0.1.1
Error: Package: nodejs-request-2.21.0-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: npm(form-data) < 0.1
           Installing: nodejs-form-data-0.1.1-1.el6.noarch (epel)
               npm(form-data) = 0.1.1
Error: Package: nodejs-npm-registry-client-0.2.28-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: npm(request) >= 2.25.0
           Installing: nodejs-request-2.21.0-1.el6.noarch (epel)
               npm(request) = 2.21.0
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I have been able to install NPM from source which is fine, but I would prefer to use the yum package.  Can anyone provide some pointers for me?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We used the epel-testing repo to install npm and bypass the issues with the epel repo

```
yum --enablerepo=epel-testing install npm
```

Update: This is fixed for the epel repo

```
yum install npm
```

Answer (score 0):

With a clean CentOS 6.5 install I only needed to get the latest epel repository here:

http://mirrors.servercentral.net/fedora/epel/6/i386/repoview/epel-release.html

You can use wget or a GUI browser to fetch the package linked on that page:

http://mirrors.servercentral.net/fedora/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

Run the rpm install and epel will be enabled by default and npm can be installed with dependencies with a standard yum install command:

```
yum install npm
```

Comment: That first link is 404